# x86 - addressing modes to access elements in arrays

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, addressing-mode

I am trying to learn assembly language. Can someone explain and/or give an example of how to use addressing modes to access elements in each of the following array types?

1. array of `DWORD`
2. array of structures, where each structure contains two `DWORD`s
3. array of arrays, where each array has 10 `DWORD`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't mention which processor specifically you are targeting, but in 386+ this would work. I don't have MASM, but MASM uses Intel syntax.

1. Let's assume that `ebx` is the base register and `esi` is the index register of the element. Standard 32-bit registers (`eax`, `ebx`, `ecx`, `edx`, `ebp`, `esi`, `edi`) are valid for the addressing mode used here. `esp` can be used as base register but not as index register. The value of index register can be optionally scaled with 2, 4 or 8. In this example we can use a scaling factor 4 for a dword array (in 386 legal scaling factors are 1, 2, 4 and 8).

   to read the value from array into `eax`: `mov eax, [ebx+4*esi]`
   to store the value of `eax` into array: `mov [ebx+4*esi], eax`
2. Let's keep still `ebx` as the base address. We can use a scaling factor 8 for `esi` for a struct array in which each struct consists of 2 dwords.

   to read the value of the first dword into `eax`: `mov eax, [ebx+8*esi]`
   to store the value of `eax` into first dword: `mov [ebx+8*esi], eax`

   to read the value of the second dword into `eax`: `mov eax, [ebx+8*esi+4]`
   to store the value of `eax` into second dword: `mov [ebx+8*esi+4], eax`

   If the index can't be hardcoded, you can just add 4 to `ebx` (or whatever registers you use to store the base address). And if you have hardcoded base-address, then you could use eg. `esi` to address the struct and eg. `ebx` to address the dword you want. Note that in 386+ you can't scale more than one register (the index register) in indirect addressing.
3. Let's still assume you don't know the base address of your array beforehand, and you'll have it in `ebx`, in `esi` you have the index of the struct and in `edx` you have the index of the dword.

   To get the address of the struct you can use `lea` multiplication optimization (10 = 8 + 2):

   **Edit:** Fix: `lea esi,[4*esi]` (dword is 4 bytes)

   `lea edi,[ebx+8*esi]`

   `lea edi,[edi+2*esi]`

   Now you have the address of the struct in `edi`. You just need to add the index of the dword (stored in `edx` in this example) multiplied by 4 (because each dword is 4 bytes).

   To read value of dword to `eax`: `mov eax,[edi+4*edx]`.

   To store value of `eax` into dword: `mov [edi+4*edx],eax`.

Comment: The normal way to do `*10` on x86 is `*5*2`, e.g. `lea reg, [reg+reg*4]` / `add reg,reg`.  You can scale by another 4 by making it `*8` instead of `*2`.  So for case 3: `lea eax, [esi+esi*4]` / `lea eax, [ebx + esi*8]` (eax holds address of the inner array/struct).  Then `mov eax, [eax + edx*4]`.  (Use whatever temporary instead of EAX, including overwriting one of the inputs.)  BTW, `shl esi, 2` would be more efficient than `lea esi, [4*esi]` where you're not also adding or copying.

Answer (score 3):

The logic is trivial.

The address of *i*-th element of a 1-dimensional array is just the address of the array (or the 0-th element) plus *i* * *element size*.

If you have a 2-dimensional array, you can treat it as a 1-dimensional array of 1-dimensional arrays and reduce it to the already familiar case I've just described: the address of *i*-th 1-dim subarray of a 2-dim array is just the address of the 2-dim array plus *i* * *subarray size*. Within that *i*-th subarray we already know how to calculate *j*-th element address.

So, the address of *(i,j)*-th element of a 2-dimensional array is just the address of the array plus *i* * *subarray size* + *j* * *element size* OR, equivalently, the address of the array plus (*i* * *number of elements in the row* + *j*) * *element size*.

You should be able to figure out how to do this in assembly language.